# how to write groovy script when field name "cmis:object" is coming in json format

Tags: json, groovy

I have requirement where i need to write groovy script for below json format:

```
{
  "objects": [
    {
      "object": {
        "properties": {
          "cmis:objectTypeId": {
            "id": "cmis:objectTypeId",
            "localName": "cmis:objectTypeId",
            "displayName": "cmis:objectTypeId",
            "queryName": "cmis:objectTypeId",
            "type": "id",
            "cardinality": "single",
            "value": "cmis:folder"
          },
          "cmis:lastModifiedBy": {
            "id": "cmis:lastModifiedBy",
            "localName": "cmis:lastModifiedBy",
            "displayName": "cmis:lastModifiedBy",
            "queryName": "cmis:lastModifiedBy",
            "type": "string",
            "cardinality": "single",
            "value": "83be71c75"
          },
          "sap:parentIds": {
            "id": "sap:parentIds",
            "localName": "sap:parentIds",
            "displayName": "sap:parentIds",
            "queryName": "sap:parentIds",
            "type": "id",
            "cardinality": "multi",
            "value": [
              "j3YMDSh8asKWzgngn7KI0JnogtswA"
            ]
          },
          "cmis:name": {
            "id": "cmis:name",
            "localName": "cmis:name",
            "displayName": "cmis:name",
            "queryName": "cmis:name",
            "type": "string",
            "cardinality": "single",
            "value": ""
          },
          "cmis:createdBy": {
            "id": "cmis:createdBy",
            "localName": "cmis:createdBy",
            "displayName": "cmis:createdBy",
            "queryName": "cmis:createdBy",
            "type": "string",
            "cardinality": "single",
            "value": "75"
          },
          "sap:owner": {
            "id": "sap:owner",
            "localName": "sap:owner",
            "displayName": "sap:owner",
            "queryName": "sap:owner",
            "type": "string",
            "cardinality": "single",
            "value": "5"
          },
          "cmis:objectId": {
            "id": "cmis:objectId",
            "localName": "cmis:objectId",
            "displayName": "cmis:objectId",
            "queryName": "cmis:objectId",
            "type": "id",
            "cardinality": "single",
            "value": "bRREGuEzQfqJTnPB0CAm6LgTTAc"
          },
          "cmis:creationDate": {
            "id": "cmis:creationDate",
            "localName": "cmis:creationDate",
            "displayName": "cmis:creationDate",
            "queryName": "cmis:creationDate",
            "type": "datetime",
            "cardinality": "single",
            "value": 1593460178
          },
          "cmis:changeToken": {
            "id": "cmis:changeToken",
            "localName": "cmis:changeToken",
            "displayName": "cmis:changeToken",
            "queryName": "cmis:changeToken",
            "type": "string",
            "cardinality": "single",
            "value": "0"
          },
          "cmis:baseTypeId": {
            "id": "cmis:baseTypeId",
            "localName": "cmis:baseTypeId",
            "displayName": "cmis:baseTypeId",
            "queryName": "cmis:baseTypeId",
            "type": "id",
            "cardinality": "single",
            "value": "cmis:folder"
          },
          "cmis:parentId": {
            "id": "cmis:parentId",
            "localName": "cmis:parentId",
            "displayName": "cmis:parentId",
            "queryName": "cmis:parentId",
            "type": "id",
            "cardinality": "single",
            "value": "j3TPDsKWzgngn7KI0JnogtswA"
          },
          "cmis:lastModificationDate": {
            "id": "cmis:lastModificationDate",
            "localName": "cmis:lastModificationDate",
            "displayName": "cmis:lastModificationDate",
            "queryName": "cmis:lastModificationDate",
            "type": "datetime",
            "cardinality": "single",
            "value": 1593442060178
          }
        },
        "exactACL": false
      }
    },
```

now i have to call cmis:name in my code . this is just one set of message . here it can be multiple  and from where i have to call cmis:name each time.
now when i tried to call cmis:name as a field - i get error  . Also i tried to assign some value to "cmis:name = a " then also i get error .

can some one guide me how to proceed

Comment: i tried below code def obj = new JsonSlurper().parseText(body); def c = obj.objects.object.properties.'cmis:name' print c here body is the input - its working. but i need the value of 'cmis:name' . e.g -"def c = obj.objects.object.properties.'cmis:name'.id"

Answer (score 0):

Those are maps, you can use:

- `obj.get('a:b:c')`
- `obj['a:b:c']`
- `obj.'a:b:c'`

Comment: i tried below code def obj = new JsonSlurper().parseText(body); def c = obj.objects.object.properties.'cmis:name' print c here body is the input - its working. but i need the value of 'cmis:name' . e.g -"def c = obj.objects.object.properties.'cmis:name'.id"